# How can I add information to another DB using Firebase Auth userID?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I know with Firebase auth they have the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function. But I was wondering, how can I copy the UID it sets for that user? Because I need to also save alternate information, so I need to send the UID to my own database as well?

Comment: There is no way to add your own arbitrary properties to the Firebase Authentication user profile. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+store+additional+information

Answer (score 1):

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword), createUserWithEmailAndPassword returns a Promise to a UserCredential object, so you can do this:

```
async function signUp(email, password, nickname) {
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    const uid = userCredential.user.uid;
    // Now you can use *uid* to store data related to your user.
    // For example in firestore:
    await firebase.firestore().doc(`/users/${uid}`).set({nickname});
    // For example as http data:
    await fetch("https://...", method="POST", body: JSON.stringify({uid, nickname});
}
```

Comment: Ah I see thank you. So if I wasnt using firestore and instead my own DB in place of `await firebase.firstore().doc(`/users/${uid}`).set({nickname, age});` I can put a JSON POST to my PHP to make the user?

Comment: Yes indeed, Firestore was just an example. Your use-case is perfectly valid, you can use uid as you want.